# Touch events does not get called in UIView class iOS Objective c

Tags: ios, uiview, touchesbegan, touchesmoved, touch-event

I have programmed a dynamic view from my main viewcontroller using below code

```
ViewClass *View;

   View = [[ViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 100, 200, 200)];
   View.layer.cornerRadius = View.frame.size.width/2;
   View.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
   View.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   View.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   [self.view addSubview:View];
```

Now i am trying to get touch events from my UIView class using below snippets

```
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    locationOfTouch = [touch locationInView:self];
}

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event{

    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    locationOfTouch = [touch locationInView:self];
}
```

but touchesBegan method does not get call, where am i going wrong. Any help would be great...

Comment: show init method of ViewClass

Comment: there is no init method in ViewClass

Comment: Is ViewClass *View a local variable?

Comment: nope.....its obj for UIView Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will help in swift

In ViewDidLoad enable userInteraction for yourCustomView

```
 yourCustomView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

call this method

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

     super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

     let touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch

     if (touch.view == yourCustomView){
     print("touchesBegan | This is an yourCustomView")
     }else{
     print("touchesBegan | This is not an yourCustomView")
     }

  }
```

Hopefully this will help..! :D